# Last digit of sum

Tags: c++

In a problem i need to find last digit of a sum's result:: S=1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4 + ... + n^4.But  , i don't know why i take only 40% at this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    long long pow = 1, result=1;
   
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            result = 1LL * pow * i;
        }
    }
    int cifra = result % 10;
    cout << cifra;




    return 0;
```

}

Ex Input 4 and output will be also 4 , because S=1+16+81+256=354, and last digit is 4

Comment: Because complexity of your algorithm is O(n2)

Comment: i dont know with complexity of my algorithm . I am very begginer.

Comment: Odds are there's some formula you can apply to solve this without any (or minimal) looping

Comment: You calculated the last number of 1^4 * 2^4 * 3^4 * ... * n^4, you calculated the product, not the sum :-)

Answer (score 2):

Last digit of product, only depends on the last digits of multiplicands.

Based on this fact the whole code can be written using only `int` in a simpler way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int pow = 1, result = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        pow = (i * i) % 10;         // last digit of i^2
        result += (pow * pow) % 10; // (last digit of i^2)^2
    }
    cout << (result % 10);

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

Inspired by [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65363315/11927652) from [Bob__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944425/bob) here is a solution with pre-calculated values. This is derived from same code as above. If you run for `n` from 1 to 1000, a pattern will emerge with a series of 100 digits. We can directly chose from them:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char digit[] = "0178495623340172895667340512899067384512239061784556239401788956273401128950673445128390677845162390";
    std::cout << digit[n % 100];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the posted code tries to evaluate the last digit of the sum (`cifra`, here):

```
// ...
long long pow = 1, result=1;
   
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        result = 1LL * pow * i;
    }
}
int cifra = result % 10;
```

It's worth noting that the net result of those two nested loop is always `result = n;` and that can't be correct (at least most of the times).

---

As noted in [Ashutosh Raghuwanshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11927652/ashutosh-raghuwanshi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65363022/4944425):

> Last digit of product, only depends on the last digits of multiplicands.

So we can easily find the last digits of the fourth power of all the ten digits

```
0, 1, 6, 1, 6, 5, 6, 1, 6, 1
```

And we can also directly compute their sum's last digit:

```
// 0, 1, 1+6 = 7, 7+1 = 8, 8+6 = 14, 14+5 = 9, ...    
int digits[] = {0, 1, 7, 8, 4, 9, 5, 6, 2, 3};
```

So that, for each `n`, the last digit of the sum of the fourth powers of `i` is

```
int digit = (3 * (n / 10) + digits[n % 10]) % 10;
// 1, 7, 8, 4, 9, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 0, 5, ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you are rookie, so try this one out

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int main()
{
    int n;
    double var = 0.0;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    //finding the total sum of given series
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
        var += pow(i, 4.0); 

    //truncating decimal values 
    var += 0.5 - (var < 0); 
    int temp = (int)var; //converting the "var" value to int so that we can use "%"

    //last digit of given sum of series    
    std::cout << temp % 10;
}
```

Comment: Don't use floating point powers for such a simple calculation.